# Zeitwerk nested module class gives undefined constant error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zeitwerk

I have the class inside lib/snowflake/connection.rb folder.

inside connection.rb file is the following structure

```
module SnowFlake
   class Connection

   end
end
```

Zeitwerk:check is throwing me following error.

expected file lib/snow_flake/connection.rb to define constant Connection

Comment: Do you mean `class Connection` rather than `class connection`?

Comment: yes class Connection

Comment: It's SnowFlake because the directory is snow_flake.

Comment: After these changes, are you still getting the error?

Comment: yes i am getting same error

Comment: Can you share loader.dirs?

Comment: Ah, you said zeitwerk:check so it has to be a Rails app. OK, I suspect the application has lib/snow_flake in the autoload paths. Note the subdirectory. Is that the case?

Comment: `SnowFlake` will cause `zietwerk` to look for a "snow_flake" directory but you are saying the directory is called "snowflake" additionally a full stack trace might be helpful as well as any modifications you have made to autoload_paths

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I am going to optimistically write an answer.

Assuming the error has been copied verbatim, I suspect your application has `lib/snow_flake` in the autoload paths. Why? Because otherwise the error would look like (small edits)

```
expected file lib/snow_flake/connection.rb to define SnowFlake::Connection
```

That is, the `SnowFlake` namespace would be included in the missing constant name reported in the error message.

Nested root directories represent the top-level namespace. If `lib/snow_flake` is added to the autoload paths, then `lib/snow_flake/connection.rb` is expected to define the top-level constant `Connection`, not `SnowFlake::Connection`.

You can inspect the autoload paths by running

```
% bin/rails runner 'pp ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths'
```

If my hypothesis is confirmed, please just remove `lib/snow_flake` from the autoload paths. It is probably being added by hand somewhere in `config/application.rb`.